# SSRS Visibility IFNOTHING or Value >=

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!actual_end.Value)) or (Fields!actual_end.Value >= DATEADD("d",-7,TODAY()),false, true)
```

I want the row to be visible if the value is blank or if the value is greater than or equal to one week ago. Having a little trouble with the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra bracket in the `IIF` expression.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!actual_end.Value) or (Fields!actual_end.Value >= DATEADD("d",-7,TODAY()),false, true)
```